# Powershell add null content and not null content to one CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, null, export-to-csv, patch

- I need to include 'Installed' and 'Not Installed' data in one CSV
- I think I need to incorporate an -OR logical operator to include TRUE/FALSE
  output in one CSV. Idk how to do that yet.
- There's a folder with many *ServerData files that contain a list of KBs with
  possible duplicate KBs.
- There is a *ServerData file for each server, with possible duplicate files.
- I want to test whether any of them contain KB2151757 and KB4556403.
- Then output the results to a csv with a status of either Installed or Not
  Installed.
- Currently it only returns a list of computers with the KB installed.
- If the $patch is not found, it currently returns nothing (null).
- For each $computer searched, it needs to return the specified fields for the
  [PSCustomObject]

I'm thinking that maybe I just need to take a function to find 'installed' and a function to find 'not installed' and add the results together to export. Idk how to do that. I feel like there must be an easier way.

[Click to view a sample of the CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h845e.png)

```
$computers = Get-Item -path F:\*ServerData | Select-Object -ExpandProperty basename

$patch = gc -path F:\*ServerData | Sort-Object -Unique | Select-String KB2151757, KB4556403 #'KB(\d+)'

$output = ForEach ($computer in $computers) {

    ForEach ($kb in $patch) { 

        if ($null -eq $patch){   
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                Status = 'Not Installed' 
                Server = $computer
                KB = $kb          
            } 

      } else{  
            [PSCustomObject]@{        
                Status = 'Installed'  
                Server = $computer
                KB = $kb
            } 
        }
    }
} 
$output | Export-csv C:\KB-Report.txt -notypeinformation -delimiter ',' -encoding utf8
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of the contents in the `*ServerData` files? ie. what does the first 5 lines of `gc -path F:\*ServerData | Sort-Object -Unique` return?

Comment: So there's one `*ServerData` csv file per server - and you'd like to test whether `KB2151757` and `KB4556403` are listed in them, and then output an object with the status per patch, per server?

Comment: There's a folder with many *ServerData files. I want to test whether any of them contain KB2151757 and KB4556403. Then output the results to a csv with a status of either Installed or Not Installed. Currently, it outputs the installed items and nothing for not installed ones.

Comment: So there might be _multiple_ CSV files pertaining to a single computer?

Comment: The *ServerData files are not csvs. The *ServerData files contain a list of installed KBs. I'm able to output a list of Installed KBs per file. I want to search for a specific KB that is not installed and return a status of not installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start by grouping the files by the associated computer name, then the procedure becomes straightforward (pseudocode):

- for each Computer

  - for each ExpectedPatch

    - if ServerData for Computer contains ExpectedPatch

      - Output object with 'Installed' status for ExpectedPatch on Computer
    - else

      - Output object with 'NotInstalled' status for ExpectedPatch on Computer

So let's give that a try:

```bsh
# Define the articles we're looking for
$ExpectedPatches = 'KB2151757', 'KB4556403'

# Enumerate and group data files by computer name, output as hashtable
# The resulting hashtable will have the computer name is Name and the associated files as its value
$ServerDataPerComputer = Get-Item -Path F:\*ServerData |Group BaseName -AsHashtable

foreach($Computer in $ServerDataPerComputer.GetEnumerator())
{
    foreach($Patch in $ExpectedPatches)
    {
        # Pipe all the file references to Select-String, look for the KB ID, return after the first match if any
        $Status = if($Computer.Value |Select-String "\b$Patch\b" |Select-Object -First 1){
          'Installed'
        }
        else {
          # Select-String didn't find the KB ID in any of the files
          'NotInstalled'
        }
    
        [pscustomobject]@{
          Status = $Status
          Server = $Computer.Name
          KB = $Patch
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow! Thank you! That makes perfect sense. I think GetEnumerator() was the crucial bit that it needed. I got hung up on null and over looked what else it was missing. Thank you again!

Comment: @JessicaNations Glad to hear it makes sense :D An alternative solution would be to loop over `$ServerDataPerComputer.Keys` (and then reference `$ServerDataPerComputer[$computer]` inside the loop to get to the files), but either will work. If my answer solves your problem, please consider marking it "accepted" by clicking the checkmark on the left :)